# i just wanna ask how can i print 0-9 numbers diagonally

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

i just wanna ask how can i print 0-9 numbers diagonally in MS-DEBUG ?
this is my code :

```
mov cx, 000a
mov ah, 02
mov dl, 30
int 21
inc dl
loop ; loop to int 21
```

and my output is this 0123456789

but the required output is this :

```
0
  1
    2
      3
        4
          5
            6
              7
                8
                  9
```

Comment: What do you mean "diagonally"?

Comment: When you mean **diagonal** do you mean something like what is displayed in this [example output](http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/stackoverflow/diagonal.txt)? You should provide in yuor question the output you expect.

Comment: im sorry for not being specific on my output ..

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mov cx, 000a
> mov ah, 02
> mov dl, 30
> int 21
> inc dl
> loop ; loop to int 21
> ```

In your code you **only change the column** component in the DL register (through the use of the DOS output function). No wonder your loop produces : 0123456789

Make a change to the row component in the DH register also and see that it will give you the desired result:

```
 mov cx, 000a
 mov bh, 00   < Use display page 0 to position the cursor on
 mov ah, 02   < Luckily BIOS and DOS have the same function number
 mov dl, 30   < This defines the start column and also the character
 mov dh, 02   < This defines the start row
again:
 int 10       < This sets the cursor
 int 21       < This outputs the character in DL
 inc dl       < This changes the column and also the character
 inc dh       < This changes the row
 loop again
```